# add as3 in frames i add in 1 frame for all time line or key frame by key frame?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

```
//this is in frame 1 to put function to movie clip in frame 3

directorio.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, exec);
function excec(e:MouseEvent):void{

trace("yes");
}
```

but if i have the same movieclip in frame  2 and 3 i need duplicate the same code.
how i can put a general code in frames?

i have 13 frames and i have problem to add as3 in frames because if i add functions frame by frame i have error of duplicated functions and if i add as3 in onli one frame for all time line i have error of propierty undefined and this already existst -> is movie clip in time line frame 3 example.

so wath is correct? :(

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) Search the web about how to create a document class in AS3

2) Create document class

3) I'm not sure what directorio is...but if it is an object go to step 4

4) Search the web on how to create a linkeage class for a library object in AS3

5) Create the linkeage class named `Directorio`

6) Write the following code inside your document class (name is `DocumentClass`)

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
public var directorio:Directorio;

public function DocumentClass()
{
    directorio = new Directorio();
    directorio.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, exec);
}

public function exec():void
{
    trace("yes");
}
```

What you're doing is a little like the United States is doing with their debt...instead of thinking of the future of your programming in AS3, you want to make a quick fix for the here and now, sacrificing everything for later. I highly suggest you go through these steps on how to learn to properly code in AS3, rather than a more succinct fix (which is possible, but I won't say how, as I think using classes is very important in AS3). Hope that helps